# How to test Angular2 pipe in nodejs with mocha without karma

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, angular, angular2-testing

I'd like to be able to test an Angular2 pipe purely in nodejs environment without including karma etc.

It is possible to use typescript files as test suites for mocha

https://templecoding.com/blog/2016/05/05/unit-testing-with-typescript-and-mocha/

But when I have a `import {Pipe} from '@angular/core'` it gives me

```
/Users/foo/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/decorators.js:173
        throw 'reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators';
        ^
reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
```

Even if I write `require('reflect-metadata')` in my test file it still breaks with the same error.

Angular internally has this check:

```
(function checkReflect() {
    if (!(Reflect && Reflect.getMetadata)) {
        throw 'reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators';
    }
})();
```

And after requireing reflect-matadata I indeed have `Reflect` on the global object, however it still doesn't work...

Anyway is there a way to test an Angular pipe purley in nodejs with mocha?

I'm using webpack to bundle the app so the file I'm requring in my test file looks like this:

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterBy'
})

export class FilterByPipe {
  transform(items = [], prop, val) {
    return items.filter(someFilteringAlgorithm(prop, val));
  }
}
```

Comment: i did something similar work with: import "reflect-metadata";

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test pipes yet, but here a post that explain how to test Angular 2 application in Node with Mocha. But It use Webpack instead of ts-node : [Here](http://hichambi.github.io/2016/12/27/testing-angular2-with-webpack-mocha-on-browser-and-node.html)

Hope It can help.